# Citing a url with bibtex using \url does not show url

Tags: bibtex, urls, ieeetran

I am using BibTeX with `ieeetran.bst` to format my bibliography and I would like to cite a URL. Initially I tried using the following code:

```
@electronic{Nobelprize.org2009,
    Author = {Nobelprize.org},
    Booktitle = {Nobel Media AB},
    Howpublished = {http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2009/},
    Title = {{The Nobel Prize in Physics 2009}},
    Year = {2013}}
```

Everything works fine except the URL is not broken. After searching for a while I found that I should use `\url` or `\href` for the correct line breaking. However, when I use

```
@electronic{Nobelprize.org2009,
        Author = {Nobelprize.org},
        Booktitle = {Nobel Media AB},
        Howpublished = {\url{http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2009/}},
        Title = {{The Nobel Prize in Physics 2009}},
        Year = {2013}}
```

the URL doesn't show at all. I am clueless as to why this may be happening. I tried including both the `url` and `hyperref` packages and although the `\url` command works in the main document, it seems it has some kind of problem when I use it in bibliography. Your help would be much appreciated.

Edit1: I should mention that I am using an adapted version of `ieeetran.bst` that correctly outputs the `howpublished` parameter.

Edit2: I solved the problem. It appears that the `IEEEtran.bst` file that I downloaded directly from IEEE was not the most recent version of this file. The one which comes with MacTeX is from 2008 while the one from IEEE is from 2007. Updating to this recent version solved my problem.

Comment: Does that style support the url field? That would be the usual way to include this information.

Comment: @cfr According to the code from the `.bst` file, I think that the only major difference between the `url` and the `howpublished` fields is that `url` automatically adds `\url{` and `}` before and after the actual url, respectively. Thus, as it happens if I manually write `\url{}`, nothing appears in the output where the url should be.

Comment: So if you specify it as the url field does it not show up either?

Comment: @cfr Correct.
I found that I was using an old version of IEEEtran. I updated it and now it's working fine, even with the adaptations I needed (to indicate the date when the website was accessed). So I guess that the problem is solved. Should I delete this post?

Comment: No idea. I would flag it for attention and let somebody who knows the site's etiquette advise.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated package version.

Comment: @JosephWright I agree. I already flagged it some days ago, as recommended by cfr.